# TypeError: object of type: 'Frame' has no len()

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror

simple tkinker program that generates an error i haven't seen before: `TypeError: object of type: 'Frame' has no len()`

I have absolutely no clue why i get this error, nor do i know what it means.

```
def gui ():
    window = tk.Tk()

    window.title('DudzRPG ' + version)

    #frames
    options = tk.Frame()
    options1 = tk.Frame()
    options2 = tk.Frame()

    #widgets
    image = tk.Canvas(bg='blue')

    opt1=tk.Button()
    opt2=tk.Button()
    opt3=tk.Button()
    opt4=tk.Button()

    #packs
    image.pack()

    options.pack()
    options1.pack()
    options2.pack()

    opt1.pack(options1)
    opt2.pack(options1)
    opt3.pack(options2)
    opt4.pack(options2)




    window.mainloop()
```

the error appears to origonate from:

```
options1 = tk.Frame()
options2 = tk.Frame()
```

which dosn't make sence to me because the above line is almost identical:

```
options = tk.Frame()
```

here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 250, in run_nodebug
  File "C:\Users\I.S.B\Google Drive\Dudzo inc python workspace\project\python thing.py", line 56, in <module>
    gui()
  File "C:\Users\I.S.B\Google Drive\Dudzo inc python workspace\project\python thing.py", line 43, in gui
    opt1.pack(options1)
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1909, in pack_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1108, in _options
    cnf = _cnfmerge(cnf)
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 105, in _cnfmerge
    for c in _flatten(cnfs):
TypeError: object of type 'Frame' has no len()
```

my question is, what does the error mean, and how do i go about fixing it?

Comment: Your errors are coming from     `opt1.pack(options1) ` down

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't calling `pack` correctly - see [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) for documentation.  The error is thrown because the `pack` function does not take a widget as a positional argument.

It seems that you are under the incorrect impression that it is the `pack` function's job to specify which widget is the child of which widget.  In fact, when you create a widget, you must tell the widget what its parent is.  Here's how to fix it:

When you create the widgets, the first argument should be the widget's intended parent widget:

```
opt1=tk.Button(options1)
opt2=tk.Button(options1)
opt3=tk.Button(options2)
opt4=tk.Button(options2)
```

Then later, when you pack them, they already know what widget they belong to:

```
opt1.pack()
opt2.pack()
opt3.pack()
opt4.pack()
```

Then in case you forgot, you need to begin the GUI's main loop:

```
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Basically the `pack` function expects a bunch of keyword arguments, but you gave it a widget, which is nonsense.  So whatever the function is doing to attempt to process the arguments is not something that can be done to a widget.  At some point, the `len` function is called on the argument, which doesn't exist because you gave it a widget.

Comment: Long story short, the error is the `pack` function's way of saying "this argument, it's not the type of thing I expected".